# Taking arguments in Godot 4 editor with @tool

Tags: rendering, editor, godot

I am trying to pass an argument from the editor to my script using @tool and @export.
My code is running properly, but I am unable to set the boolean as 'on' or 'off' in the editor.

```
@tool
extends Sprite2D

@export var show_sprites = false:
    set(show):
        if show:
            _renderSprites()
        else:
            _clearSprites()
```

[image]

Could someone show me how to properly implement @export such that it may take a boolean parameter?

A workaround I have been using is:
I use an integer as my export variable, and then: when I set a non-zero value to the integer,
the editor updates to show my sprites but does not update the parameter to the number I enter (stays 0).
I can then hit reset on the parameter in the editor to run my _clearSprites() function.

I've looked over this the past couple of days but am not making much progress:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/running_code_in_the_editor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting your variable. You need to set it inside the setter...

Something like this:

```
@export var show_sprites := false:
    set(mod_value):
        show_sprites = mod_value
        if show_sprites:
            _renderSprites()
        else:
            _clearSprites()
```

---

You might also avoid redundant work by checking if the value that is being set is the same as it has:

```
@export var show_sprites := false:
    set(mod_value):
        if show_sprites == mod_value:
            return

        show_sprites = mod_value
        if show_sprites:
            _renderSprites()
        else:
            _clearSprites()
```

---

If the change you are doing can only happen if the node is ready (e.g. because it needs to access other nodes), then you might benefit from extracting it to a separate method, so any change before the node is ready can be delayed until the node is ready:

```
@export var show_sprites := false:
    set(mod_value):
        if show_sprites == mod_value:
            return

        show_sprites = mod_value
        if is_node_ready():
            update_show_sprites()


func update_show_sprites() -> void:
    if show_sprites:
        _renderSprites()
    else:
        _clearSprites()


func _ready() -> void:
    update_show_sprites()
```

---

If you also need to support the case where the node is removed from the scene tree, the variable is modified, and then the node is added back to the scene tree, we can call `request_ready` when the node exits the scene tree, so Godot will call `_ready` again next time it enterst the scene tree:

```
@export var show_sprites := false:
    set(mod_value):
        if show_sprites == mod_value:
            return

        show_sprites = mod_value
        if is_node_ready():
            update_show_sprites()


func update_show_sprites() -> void:
    if show_sprites:
        _renderSprites()
    else:
        _clearSprites()


func _ready() -> void:
    update_show_sprites()


func _exit_tree() -> void:
    request_ready()
```

---

By the way, if you modify other properties, or the value you set to the property is not the same as requested, or for whatever reason the property is not updated in the inspector... Call `notify_property_list_changed()` so Godot reads the properties again and updates the inspector.

Calling `notify_property_list_changed()` results in Godot calling `get_property_list`. So, if you have a dynamic list of properties (which you could have by overriding `_get_property_list`), you call `notify_property_list_changed()` to tell Godot that the list changed (hence the name).

---

If you need to take control over the default values, override `_property_can_revert` and `_property_get_revert`.

Comment: 10/10 this answer was wonderfully informative :)